# Coverage probability and the nominal coverage probability frequently

Tags: probability, terminology, coverage-probability

What is the difference between coverage probability and the nominal coverage probability frequently?

Comment: I think coverage probability is the true coverage probability while nominal coverage probability is the one you want to achieve.